# Difference between methods for AngularJS checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsbin.com/hedobibone/edit?html,js,output
I have an object named `meta`

```
 {
  "content.categories": [
    "animation",
    "documentary"
  ]
 }
```

and I'm putting them in a checkbox. 
What I would like to know is the differences between doing

```
<label ng-repeat="content in meta['content.categories'] | orderBy" class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{content}}Checkbox" ng-model="inputCat[content]" ng-click="selectContent()" name="{{content}}">{{content}}
</label>


<label class="account-label">Role</label>
<label ng-repeat="role in meta['user.role'] | orderBy" class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox{{role}}" value="user.role/{{role}}" ng-click='toggleRole("user.role/" + role);'>{{role}}
</label>
```

The first one creates an object with `true` or `false` and the second one creates an array with just the values.

I'm going to submit what the users checks.

The second one does the pre-work of creating an array and pushing or removing, while the user is selecting the checkboxes.

The first one I would iterate and push to an array once the user clicks on the submit button.

**Which one is more efficient?**

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your actual problem is. Plus the code handling your checkboxes perhaps is a vital clue missing.

Comment: Flagged as opinion based question.

Comment: @skubski I added a demo

Comment: @takendarkk - cool thanks?

Comment: How can you *not* take this as opinion based, when your question is presenting two functional options and asking for an arbitrary comparison?

Comment: Well, next time I flag one of your questions I won't give you the courtesy of informing you. I'll just do it and move on.

Comment: @Claies they are doing two different functional things. Please check the jsbin.

Comment: I completely understand that they are different.  My point is, they are both *work*.  Performance of these two options can't be reasonably compared, since they produce different results. Your question therefore comes down to "which one is the better one to use", which is completely a matter of opinion, and can't be answered with a single "this one is always right and this one is always wrong" kind of answer, making it out of scope for the format of this site.

Comment: also, upon further review, I'm quite confused by the fact that the code in your jsbin doesn't even resemble the two code snippets you posted here at all.

Comment: my *opinion* on the matter, however, is that you should code for your data, not for your DOM.  Don't use DOM elements that require parsing in order to match up with your data, and don't create elements that break with or buffer between the two way bindings that angular is built around.